# How to work with RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument, richtext

I have a WPF application in which I want to convert a TextBox into a RichTextBox. I have already written the following lines of code:

```
            <RichTextBox>
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run Text="{Binding GeneralDescription}" />
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
```

This has the effect that the string GeneralDescription is displayed and I can edit and format it. Now I have the problem that when I mark a part of the text, format it (e.g. make it bold), save the document and re-open the document, only the part of the text until the formatting is displayed. I am not sure if the error lies within the display or within the saving. In either case it's annoying. How can I make it work? Is it a problem that GeneralDescription is of type string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked in your database to see what's been saved?

Comment: I think it will create multiple runs. Standart - Formatted - Standart. Seems like it is only taking the first one...

Comment: Do you save the Flowdocument ? How do you Format the Text. If you you save the Flowdocument it should work....

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is that your `string` data contains only plain text and your `XAML design tags` in it will be ignored at loading.

---

`Textbox` and `RichTextBox` are controls with a complete different behavior.

The problem also is that `RichTextBox` don't support this kind of binding native. A Document on a `RichTextBox` is not a dependency property, that's why.

Personally i use [David Veeneman](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66054/A-Bindable-WPF-RichTextBox) extended control for cases like this.

---

For Saving or Loading a `FlowDocument` directly use:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
XamlWriter.Save(myFlowDocumentObject, fs);
```

and

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
FlowDocument myFlowDocumentObject = XamlReader.Load(fs) as FlowDocument;
```

---

By the way, the `Run` Tag data binding is partially supported.

- One way data binding is fully supported. A Run can be bound to a data
  source and the content of the Run will reflect the value of what it
  is bound to. The bound Run will receive and display any changes that
  occur in the data source.
- **Two way data binding is partially supported**. If a bound Run is
  updated via calls to the WPF property system, the data source which
  the Run is bound to will reflect the changes to the Run. On the other
  hand, **if a bound Run is updated via a RichTextBox** or the text object
  model, **the Run will lose its binding**.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the code provided at this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37169/WPF-RichText-Editor